# Updating Sharepoint Calendar events + c#

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

How can we update a sharepoint calendar without overlapping an existing event?
Say, the calendar list already has an event with EventDate - 25/Aug/2013 4:00:00 and 26/Aug/2013 15:00:00 . Now, how can I insert a new event without overlapping an already existing event?

Note: I am able to insert items to Calendar using C# code. But, I just need to know whether there is a way to insert the events without overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box when activating Group work related features you will get a double booking feature checker (see more here http://blog.sharepointsydney.com.au/post/Setting-up-multiple-calendars-for-meeting-room-bookings-prevent-double-booking.aspx).

On the other hand programmatically one way could still be via Item event handlers (you need to down and dirty with CAML building around dates, as in  http://kartooz.wordpress.com/2009/02/20/querying-sharepoint-calendar-for-recurring-events-using-caml-query/ or a very good insight on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manuj/archive/2009/09/22/creating-a-global-events-list-and-displaying-in-calendarview.aspx) or if you prefer JSOM you could rely on ListData.svc.